# SQL Server : having and where clauses for column names selected with "as"

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause, having

I am trying to get the results for a similar query on Microsoft SQL Server:

```
SELECT 
    A, B, C AS DANUMBER 
FROM 
    TABLE
WHERE 
    B = 'SOMEVALUE'
HAVING 
    DANUMBER > 0
```

However, I can not use the column I have selected with "AS" in SQL Server. The **DANUMBER** is simply unknown to the server.

Every example I looked up informs about showing aggregate functions, nothing solved my problem. This query works on mySQL, but not on SQL Server.

I think I may be missing some syntax or something...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL extends the use of the `HAVING` clause to recognize column aliases defined in the `SELECT`.  You cannot assume this behavior in other databases (it doesn't work in SQL Server and Oracle, for instance, it does work in Postgres).  You have three choices:  repeat the expression, use a subquery, or use a CTE.

The first is the best for code that might be running in both SQL Server and MySQL:

```
SELECT A, B, C AS DANUMBER 
FROM TABLE
WHERE B = 'SOMEVALUE'
GROUP BY A, B, C
HAVING C > 0;
```

or:

```
SELECT A, B, C AS DANUMBER 
FROM TABLE
WHERE B = 'SOMEVALUE' AND 
      C > 0;
```

Comment: Pretty sure it doesn't work in Postgres. This syntax can't work sensibly in any DBMS that implements window functions as the alias could refer to an expression calculated after the `having`.

Comment: oh my god. I did not want to repeat the expression thinking that it will redo the operation because it is a paranthesis with some load in it. but as your explanation goes it seems that there is no choice :-/

Comment: Having means that after the where clause and joins are done any results are filtered to see if they pass the condition set by the having clause. Having is often used in a count or sum query where you want to only see results that are larger then some condition. Using having in the example you provided does not make sense. You want a where with an and clause.

Comment: The suggested answer still won't work in TSQL because there is no `GROUP BY`, nor are aggregates applied to A or B (or C).  The good news for the OP is that you can often factor out the expression into an earlier query expressed in a `WITH` clause  -- but I can't suggest one w/o understanding the GROUP.

Comment: @benjaminmoskovits the C symbolizes a subquery type of result